# Display correct values on report in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two reports for reconciliation where a TotalCost of 785275.20 should be displayed as same on both reports. However on Report2, there is a difference of 650.

- Report1: 785275.20
- Report2: 784625.20

This is the stored procedure:

```
Create Table #TempTablex
(
    CostPay money
);

INSERT INTO #TempTableX (CostPay)
    SELECT 
        SUM(c.item1 + c.item2 + c.item3 + c.item4) AS TotalCost
    FROM 
        Cost AS C   
    WHERE 
        ((c.item1 + c.item2 >= 0))
        AND NOT ((c.item3 + c.item4 < 0))

SET sql = 'SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Temp.CostPay), 0) AS CostPay
           FROM #TempTableX Temp'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Any help how I can get both reports to display same `GrossPay`?

Comment: No didn't try it. Was thinking this could be an error from the sum..

Comment: Read again your dynamic query.

Comment: your dynamic query is having an extra *`,`* after `CostPay`

Comment: how about some sample data?

Comment: This procedure returns a single result.  If you're running it twice, once for each report, any data updates to cost between runs would yield a difference in sums.

Comment: @user3687828 How even this work? you have a temp table `#TempTableX`, but in your query you select from `TempTableX`. is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a timing issue.

```
Run Report1 -> 785275.20
User increases item1 on row1 by 650
Run Report2 -> 7856275.20
```

You're not showing how the reports are run.  Are they part of a single job?  If you're looking for read consistency, you need to run both reports within a single transaction with the isolation level set appropriately.

From your comment that these are SSRS reports running on a website, I'm considering that the source data is being updated in real time.  To get static results from both reports, you need to create a snapshot of the data.  How you accomplish the snapshot depends on the complexity of the reports.  But if it's only the data in the procedure you've given, I'd just insert the procedure results into a table and then run each report from the table instead of the procedure.

Comment: Agree with you LAS, the procedure is run once for both reports. Its SSRS reports being viewed on a webpage. Is there a way to avoid getting that difference?